# asp.net mvc jquery tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tabs

I was looking at [here](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) to create a dynamic tab in asp.net mvc using jQuery.

I have an add button in my view that will call jquery function to go to url via ajax and return a partialView which uses

```
Html.BeginCollectionItem()
```

So far I've done to increase counter for my tabs (ex: Employee1, Employee2), and can bring partial view and render it in the tab content, but what happens is information I entered in Employee1 tab content is directly copied and regenerated in Employee2 content. (Ex: FullName in Employee1 content is appeared in Employee2 content) How can I remove previous tab content data and generate a new one?

And also when I clicked on add button, partial view content is added vertically as well as horizontally. This seemed really weird.

So my View:

```
button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>

<div id="tabs">
            <ul>                                  
            </ul>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="tabs-1"></div>   
            </div>                           
        </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabCounter = 1;
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employee/AddNewEmployee',
        }).success(function (partialView) {
            addTab(partialView);
        });
    });

    function addTab(partialView) {
        var id = "Employee" + tabCounter;
        var title = "Employee" + tabCounter;
        $('#content').append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + partialView + "</p></div>");            
        $('#tabs').tabs("add", id, title);
        tabCounter++;
    }
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddNewEmployee()
    {
        return PartialView("_EmployeePartial");
    }
```

EmployeePartial:

```
@model Test.Models.Employee

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("employees"))
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })         
</div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just needed to look at the jQuery API documentation more closely.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>                    
    </ul>

 </div>    

<script>
$(function () {
    var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
        tabCounter = 2;

    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#add').on('click', function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Application/AddNewEmployee',
        }).success(function (partialView) {
            addTab(partialView);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
    function addTab(partialView) {
        var label = "Tab " + tabCounter,
          id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
          li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label));

        tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
        tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + partialView + "</p></div>");
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabCounter++;
    }

    // Close icon: removing the tab on click
    tabs.on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function () {
        var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
        $("#" + panelId).remove();
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
    });

    tabs.on("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE) {
            var panelId = tabs.find(".ui-tabs-active").remove().attr("aria-controls");
            $("#" + panelId).remove();
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```